# How do I filter the processes and services in the Task manager based on how active they are

Tags: windows-7, windows, task-manager

I am trying to identify from the Task Manager the static and dynamic activities of my system in order to store them into a database.

An example of what I call static processes are like some services or processes start once the system starts or a user log-in, and they are never closed unless that user logged-out or the system has been shutdown. If you noticed these processes while opening the Task manager, you can see their related information do not change.

Those which their information keep in changing I call them dynamics process and I need them to be stored in a database every-time their values change.

My question is: can I filter the Task manager to display only those active dynamic processes and services ?

.. and if possible, i need a link that explains the life-cycle of the services and processes of windows-7 or any windows ... thanks

Comment: It's going to be extremely difficult to use "Activity" as a criteria. I know many services which are *very* active and change a lot, and many user processes which idle the entire time. What do you do with a program which is very active for 10 minutes, and then is idle the rest of the day, and then very active again the next day?

Comment: @DarthAndroid: I was thinking of updating my database based on if a service's values have changed or not, if, at least one value, has changed then the whole row of the database will be updated with the new value if not then keep the old values.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: btw, what about the life-cycle .. do you have any useful link ? .. I would like to underestand the Task Manger better

Comment: I don't think the Windows Task Explorer can do this by default.  You can look into [other third party tools that also provide process management](https://windowsreport.com/best-task-manager-software-windows-10/)

Comment: You can't. WIndows is 30 years old and Microsoft hasn't figured it out yet.

Comment: [Process Explorer from MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) seems more sophisticated than task manager. most recently updated 2 months prior to me writing this in 2021.